# Going back to the calling class from new class

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I go back to the calling class from the new class, I have performed all my functions in new class and now I want to go back from where the intent was called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call finish() or finishActivity(); functions to return back to the calling class and finish the current activity.

Answer (score 2):

If you start an Activity from another Activity without calling `finish();` in the initial activity, just call `finish();` in the second activity. (Note: This will kill your second activity)